# Want some general info about 'Golden Testing'

Tags: testing, regression

I want to know about what 'golden testing' is.

In my investigation, there is a golden file and it is the expected result. And daily regression test compares today's output file with the golden file.

1. Can someone explain the theory of golden testing?
2. And practically how can I implement this test program?

   - I want also recommended framework libraries for this.
   - Does boost.Test cover this kind of testing?

Thank you very much! in advance.

Comment: From the boost mailing list (the url below), I received an useful answer for my question. http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2013/04/78334.php I decided to read and apply "Fit for Developing Software: Framework for Integrated Tests". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Someone can add the frameworks for implementing golden test as I don't have much knowledge about that. I can give an overview about the theory.

Golden testing is just like a normal testing where you run something and expect it to generate a specified output. It is used in integration tests where systems interact with all the external resources like services and databases. Let's consider the name of the system `S` which taken input `I`, does some computation and outputs `O`

**Input**
The input of `S` is fixed. Let's name it `S_fix` We store it somewhere and call it golden input (we can consider golden as a synonym for constant). `S_fix` will be fed into `S` everytime the golden testing is executed.

**Output**
The system `S` does the processing and outputs `O`, we already know what should be the output of `S`(let's call it `O_golden`) based on the input `I` we are providing. We store this expected output somewhere and call it the golden output. Now, the output of `S` at the current execution is `O_current`. Our expectation is that `O_golden = O_current`. If this is the case then we can assume that the `S` is working fine.

`**O_current != O_golden**`
If there is a difference between the current output and the golden output (the current output is not equal to the output we expected), there can be 2 cases:

1. We know that there was some changes in `S` and the output is expected to change and the current output of `S` is what should be expected (not the golden output `O_golden`). In this case we have to update the `O_golden` to `O_current` as the expected output is changed because of changes in S. This process is called `golden update`.
2. We are expecting `O_current = O_golden` but it isn't. This says that there must be some defect in `S`. In this case we have to verify the recent changes in `S` that may have caused this changed output.

The golden testing is generally run before adding a new change in the system so that every change in the system is monitored by this test.

We can configure the diffing of `O_current` and `O_golden` based on our needs. Tools generally provide a config file to be filled for diffing. Sometimes the output of a system also contains timestamps or data which depends on execution time or anything which is not related to the system. Hence there will be diffs in `O_current` and `O_golden` is the output has these kind of data. We can configure the diffing process to ignore a particular type of data if that is not required.